# Unable to get GPS Location with Common Code

Tags: android, gps, android-location

I have code to get location, which I believe must be working but it doesn't at all:

**Manifest**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

**Java**:

```
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
            0, 
            0,
            new MyLocationListener()
    );

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);

    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    System.out.println("location: " + location);
```

location prints null and the listener never get called at all. Anyone can advise what's wrong? If I open Google Maps, it can return my location anyway.

**Note:** I am testing with my device

Comment: do it this way just check this link it will helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android

Comment: what is mLocationManager? because in your code you are using locationManager for registering updates, so you should use locationManager instead

Comment: @Gautam sorry forgot to edit that one.

Answer (score 1):

Create Class `SingleShotLocationProvider`  in your utility package or wherever you are fine with below code.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SingleShotLocationProvider {

    public  interface LocationCallback {
         void onNewLocationAvailable(Location location);
    }

    // calls back to calling thread, note this is for low grain: if you want higher precision, swap the
    // contents of the else and if. Also be sure to check gps permission/settings are allowed.
    // call usually takes <10ms
    public static void requestSingleUpdate(final Context context, final LocationCallback callback) {
        final LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


        if (Utility.checkAndRequestPermissionsForGPS(context)) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "First enable LOCATION ACCESS in settings.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            boolean isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
                locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(criteria, new LocationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                        callback.onNewLocationAvailable(location);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                    }
                }, null);
            } else {
                boolean isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
                    locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(criteria, new LocationListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                            callback.onNewLocationAvailable(location);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                        }
                    }, null);
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Now in you Activity import it like

```
import com.yourdomain.utils.SingleShotLocationProvider;
```

Now you can use it like below `this` is reference to your activity

```
 SingleShotLocationProvider.requestSingleUpdate(this,
                    new SingleShotLocationProvider.LocationCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onNewLocationAvailable(Location location) {
                            if (location != null) {
                                double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                                }
                             } 
                    }
                });
```

You will receive location in first attempt just make sure GPS is on and set to high accuracy.And in manifest you have given necessary permission as like below -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. I am using the GPS here to get the latitude and longitude.

```
   Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    // Getting the name of the best provider
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    // Getting Current Location
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    if (location != null) {
        System.out.println("Get Last LOcation" + location.getLatitude()
                + location.getLongitude());
        loc.setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
        loc.setLongitude(location.getLongitude());

    }
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (location.getAccuracy() < 50) {
                locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
            }
        }
    };

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,
            INTERVAL_TIME_SECONDS, MIN_DISTANCE_METERS,
            locationListener);
```